# GRUB disregards config file

Tags: ubuntu, grub, boot-loader

Running a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machine, I noticed something off after a kernel upgrade. The GRUB config under `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` lists **only** the 4.4.0 kernel but, when booting the machine, I can only choose from several different versions of the 4.2.0 kernel. I'm clueless about where GRUB actually pulls its config from, as it seems to disregard the settings under said path, created by `sudo update-grub`.

Edit: Grep output this question is based on

```
$ grep 'menuentry' /boot/grub/grub.cfg

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
  menuentry_id_option=""
export menuentry_id_option
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-f0724a95-d885-4cec-b74c-635d61f32c73' {
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-f0724a95-d885-4cec-b74c-635d61f32c73' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-53-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-53-generic-advanced-f0724a95-d885-4cec-b74c-635d61f32c73' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-53-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-53-generic-recovery-f0724a95-d885-4cec-b74c-635d61f32c73' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-51-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-51-generic-advanced-f0724a95-d885-4cec-b74c-635d61f32c73' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-51-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-51-generic-recovery-f0724a95-d885-4cec-b74c-635d61f32c73' {
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+)' {
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)' {
```

Comment: What is the output of `grep 'menuentry' /boot/grub/grub.cfg` ?

Comment: This output is the basis of my question, as I thought of this, too, but it only outputs 4.4.0 versions.